# Redirecting output to file then back to console in Java

Tags: java, io-redirection

Using Eclipse or DrJava, if my program in Java contains the following code in order to redirect output to a file, how do I a few lines later in the program redirect output back to the console?

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt")));
```

or

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new File ("output.txt)));
```

Comment: Why not use the file stream directly, instead of setting System.out to it, writing to System.out and then setting it back?

Comment: I second the "Don't do that" advice.  Just call `println()` on the PrintStream if you want to send data there.

Comment: can you show me the sample code for this methodology?  thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to hold onto the old stream.

```
PrintStream oldout = System.out;

System.setOut(...);

....

System.setOut(oldout);
```

The `System.out` and `System.err` are very old ways to do things and are not very useful. They should only be used in small throw away programs.

Comment: I had tried that.  However, after I reset, System.out.println() works on the console as intended, but the StdOut library created by Sedgewick for his Princeton (Coursera) courses did not print to the console.

Comment: It won't  because it is caching the output stream locally so any changes to System.out will not be noticed. What you want to do is make System.out a delegate stream and then change what it delegates too.